# How to determine if a decimal fraction can be represented exactly as Python float?

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-accuracy

From the Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations):

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as
>   binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal
>   floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary
>   floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

I wonder how can I check if a given decimal fraction will be represented exactly as a Python `float`. For instance, `0.25` can be represented exactly while `0.1` can't:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3
False
>>> 0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25 == 0.75
True
```

Comment: If it is a fraction of power of 2?

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover Python's concrete float implementation by testing that the nominator will fit in the float's exponent and fraction binary represenations. Where those the bits that were missing and the reason you removed the 'accepted' mark perhaps? :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) to check if a given fraction can be represented:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def can_be_represented(num, den):
    f = Fraction(num, den)
    return Fraction.from_float(float(f)) == f
```

Because floating point numbers use *binary fractions*, you'll soon find that this can be simplified to checking for a denominator that is a power of two:

```
def can_be_represented(num, den):
    f = Fraction(num, den)
    return f.denominator & (f.denominator - 1) == 0
```

However, this doesn't make any bounds checks on the numerator, add a bounds check by comparing with the information from [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info):

```
import sys

def can_be_represented(num, den):
    f = Fraction(num, den)
    return (
        # denominator is a power of 2
        f.denominator & (f.denominator - 1) == 0 and
        # numerator exponent can be represented
        f.numerator.bit_length() <= sys.float_info.max_exp and
        # numerator significant bits can be represented without loss
        len(format(f.numerator, 'b').rstrip('0')) <= sys.float_info.mant_dig
    )
```

The above version tests:

- That the denominator is a power of 2
- That the numerator binary exponent can be represented
- That the portion of the numerator that contains significant information can be shifted to fit in the mantissa of a float.

An optimised but less readable version of the above is:

```
def can_be_represented(num, den,
                      _mexp=sys.float_info.max_exp,
                      _mdig=sys.float_info.mant_dig):
    f = Fraction(num, den)
    num, den = f.numerator, f.denominator
    numbl = num.bit_length()
    return (
        # denominator is a power of 2
        den & (den - 1) == 0 and
        # numerator exponent can be represented
        numbl <= _mexp and
        # numerator significant bits can be represented without loss
        (numbl <= _mdig or num << numbl - _mdig >> numbl - _mdig == num)
    )
```

Comment: If the aim is to check that something is representable as a Python float (rather than simply exactly representable in arbitrary-precision binary floating-point), then checking that the denominator is a power of two isn't enough: you'd also need to check that the numerator is suitably bounded. (And that underflow and overflow are avoided.) For an easy counterexample, consider the case `10**23`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: right, so the simplification doesn't apply. I've now added bounds checks for the numerator bit length and shift distance.

Answer (score 3):

On that very page:

> On most machines today, floats are approximated using a binary
>   fraction with the numerator using the first 53 bits starting with the
>   most significant bit and with the denominator as a power of two.

Thus for a decimal fraction to be exactly representable as `float` it must be a fraction with a denominator which is a power of 2:

```
>>> 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 == 3/10  # 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
False
>>> 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 == 3/4      # 0.25 + 0.25 + 0.25
True
```

Comment: And the numerator's magnitude must be less than 2^53, and the exponent must be in range (possibly changing the numerator's maximum value in the case of a denormal). The question seems to be about a sufficient condition, the necessary condition that this answer provides is a bit weak.

Answer (score 1):

In Squeak Smalltalk, you would find this method:

```
Fraction>>isAnExactFloat
    "Answer true if this Fraction can be converted exactly to a Float"
    ^ denominator isPowerOfTwo
        and: ["I have a reasonable significand: not too big"
            numerator highBitOfMagnitude <= Float precision
                and: ["I have a reasonable exponent: not too small"
                    Float emin + denominator highBitOfMagnitude <= Float precision]]
```

and

```
Integer>>isAnExactFloat
    "Answer true if this Integer can be converted exactly to a Float"
    | h |
    (h := self highBitOfMagnitude) <= Float precision
        ifTrue: [^ true].
    ^ h - 1 <= Float emax
        and: [h - self abs lowBit < Float precision]
```

Of course it's not Python, but it's the same underlying floating point, so that shouldn't be that hard to translate...