# Python: How to determine which float values can be precisely represented and raise warning when not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, overflow, underflow

I know my version of python uses 64-bit representation, so there should be some formula for calculating which floats are precisely representable.

```
>>> 3.00000000000000022203 == 3.0
True
>>> 3.00000000000000022205 == 3.0
False
```

How would I properly catch when a level of precision can't be exactly represented?

> If the aim is to check that something is representable as a Python
>   float (rather than simply exactly representable in arbitrary-precision
>   binary floating-point), then checking that the denominator is a power
>   of two isn't enough: you'd also need to check that the numerator is
>   suitably bounded. (And that underflow and overflow are avoided.) For
>   an easy counterexample, consider the case 10**23 - Mark Dickinson from [How to determine if a decimal fraction can be represented exactly as Python float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371807/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-fraction-can-be-represented-exactly-as-python-float)

That post only talked about how to handle decimal fractions though, and not extremely larger numbers too.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate whether your float literal can be represented exactly, but what could would it do to raise an exception? If you used a float, it's because you needed that float.  Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do.

You can use Decimal to store decimal literals more accurately if you need to.

Comment: Let's say it's a large legacy system, and there are formulas that involve scaling floats substantially over time, but can produce extremely wrong results due to significant compounding errors. Converting every float to a decimal literal would be ideal, but there's no guarantee that the floats themselves were reliable to begin with, so we're starting from a state of uncertainty.